# How to integrate the fence_cisco_ucs.py(python) script with the pacemaker-1.1.10 and corosync-2.3.3

Tags: high-availability, pacemaker, corosync

I have CentOS 7 on the Oracle VM VirtualBox. I have installed the pacemaker-1.1.10, corosync-2.3.3 and pcs tools. I able to create `normalocf::heartbeat:IPaddr2` and `ocf::heartbeat:apache` etc resources. I am trying to have stonith based resource agent in my 2 node cluster.
I have copied the `fence_cisco_ucs.py` file in `/usr/sbin/` folder and executed :

> $./fence_cisco_ucs.py -o status -p x -s y
>
> Status: ON

When I tried to create the STONITH based/class resource as :

> $pcs stonith create fence_cisco_ucs fence_cisco_ucs

I am getting below error:

> Error: Unable to create resource 'stonith:fence_cisco_ucs', it is not installed on this system (use --force to override)

My question is, how to create stonith based(class) resource agent in my 2 node cluster using `fence_cisco_ucs` script.

My 2 node cluster details is here please:

```
$pcs status

Cluster name: my_cluster
Last updated: Fri Dec  5 06:03:38 2014
Last change: Fri Dec  5 06:03:00 2014 via crmd on z1
Stack: corosync
Current DC: z1 (1) - partition with quorum
Version: 1.1.10-32.el7_0.1-368c726

2 Nodes configured
3 Resources configured
Node z2 (2): standby
Online: [ z1 ]
```

Full list of resources:

```
 ClusterIP      (ocf::heartbeat:IPaddr2):       Started z1

 httpd_res      (ocf::heartbeat:apache):        Started z1

 my_c_res       (ocf::heartbeat:anything):      Started z1
```

PCSD Status:

```
  z1: Online

  z2: Online
```

Daemon Status:

```
  corosync: active/enabled
  pacemaker: active/enabled
  pcsd: active/enabled
```

Comment: On what operating system? What have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to (and shouldn't attempt to) install bits and pieces manually, since you installed acemaker and corosync from packages. The `fence_cisco_ucs` script is already packaged for you in the `fence-agents-cisco-ucs` package, and that is what Pacemaker is expecting to find.

```
yum install fence-agents-cisco-ucs
```